# Python: Program keeps getting into a infinite loop when using float

Tags: python, loops

Here is my original working program:

```
def num_rushes(required_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0
    while current_height < required_height:
        rushes += 1
        current_height += rush_height_gain
        if current_height >= required_height:
            break
        else:
            current_height -= back_sliding
    return rushes

print num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
```

What this program does it calculates how many "rushes" it takes until we reach the desired height (`required_height`), after each rush (`rush_height_gain`), we fall back by a given amount (`back_sliding`).

What I am trying to is after each rush, is multiply the height gained by 0.95 (we lose 5% of the rush each time).

As you can see below, what I have done is converted rush_height_gain to a float and then added the line `rush_height_gain *= 0.95` into my while loop, however for some reason, which I cannot seem to figure out, I end up with an infinite loop.

```
def num_rushes(required_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
    current_height = 0
    rushes = 0
    rush_height_gain = float(rush_height_gain)
    while current_height < required_height:
        rushes += 1
        current_height += rush_height_gain
        if current_height >= required_height:
            break
        else:
            current_height -= back_sliding
        rush_height_gain *= 0.95
    return rushes

print num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
```

Any help as to why this occurs and how can I get my desired result would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

`rush_high_gain` gets smaller with each pass through the `while-loop`. But `back_sliding` stays constant. If enough passes are made through the loop (about 15), `rush_height_gain` may be less than `backsliding`. At that point `current_height` will get smaller and smaller, and you will never exit the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I have now converted back_sliding to a float, and also multiplied that by 0.95 (which now actually makes a lot more sense than what I was doing before) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you temporarily add a `print` statement into your loop to show the values of relevant variables at each iteration, you'll see that because you keep shrinking `rush_height_gain`, it eventually becomes smaller than `back_sliding`. Once that happens, the object slides back further than it goes up at each step, so you wind up actually *losing* height. That means that if you haven't reached `required_height` by that point, you never will.

Probably the easiest solution is to change your loop condition to stop if `current_height` becomes negative, or alternatively if `rush_height_gain` becomes less than `back_sliding`. Alternatively, you could change the way you compute `rush_height_gain` so that it never becomes less than `back_sliding`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I have now converted back_sliding to a float, and also multiplied that by 0.95 (which now actually makes a lot more sense than what I was doing before) and it works perfectly.